# How prevent that Bind DNS updates remove $INCLUDE directive

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a DNS server up and running with a zone configured for my domain with the `allow-update` directive enabled. I have the initial configuration for the domain in the file `/var/cache/bind/db.mydomain.com` this file has a line with `$INCLUDE db.aux.mydomain.com` directive to load records from this file.

The problem comes when I do an update of the zone using `nsupdate` because bind rewrites the file `db.mydomain.com` by deleting the `$INCLUDE` line and putting the content of `db.aux.mydomain.com` directly in `db.mydomain.com` file.

How I can prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid that.

When you enable dynamic updates for a zone you are essentially handing the control of the zone file contents to bind; you are no longer allowed to make changes directly in the file and bind will need to rewrite it after updates.

As for `$INCLUDE` in that context, what would bind be expected to do if it were to keep the include statements?

Would it be expected to modify all of the referenced files as necessary when making updates?

What if some of include files are referenced from multiple zones?

What if you add a record for `foo.aux.mydomain.com`? Bind would have no idea that the filenames mean something to you, it wouldn't know to add the entry in that file specifically.

If dynamic updates are not supposed to apply to that subdomain a better option may actually be to delegate and have that as a separate zone.

Comment: I solved the problem by using separate zones, one dynamic zone handled by bind and another static zone where i write manually the static entries.